# ERROR: Failed to run install_ubuntu_stable_deps()!

Tags: salt-stack

I tried following the [SaltStack Getting Started tutorial](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/fundamentals/install.html#) and failed during salt install.

The error message is:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
pciutils is already the newest version.
procps is already the newest version.
python-apt is already the newest version.
python-requests is already the newest version.
upstart is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:saltstack/salt'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
 * ERROR: Failed to run install_ubuntu_stable_deps()!!!
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: This would be better suited to askubuntu.com .

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: The root cause of this issue is usually: `E: The repository 'https://repo.saltproject.io/py3/ubuntu/21.10/amd64/latest hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.` 

See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to manually install salt:
-   `wget -O - https://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/ubuntu14/latest/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub | sudo apt-key add` –
-   Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:   `deb http://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/ubuntu14/latest trusty main`
-   `sudo apt-get update`
-   `sudo apt-get install-master`
-   `sudo apt-get install-minion`
-   `sudo apt-get install-ssh`
-   `sudo apt-get install-syndic`
Now need to configure and restart salt master and minions
-   `vi /etc/salt/master`
-   Change line "`#interface: 0.0.0.0`" to "`interface: 192.168.50.10`"  - find IP address using command "`ifconfig | grep inet`"
-   Restart salt-master:  `service salt-master restart`
-   For minions, `vi /etc/salt/minion`
-   Change line "`#master: salt`" to "`master 192.168.50.10`" – so that it can talk to salt master
-   Restart salt-minion: `service salt-minion restart`
Now master need to accept keys from minions
-   To display all keys: `salt-key –list-all`   - you should see 2 keys listed under unaccepted
-   To accept all keys: `salt-key –A`
Now master should be able to communicate with minions.
-   To test: `salt  '*' test.ping`  - which should return all minions with "True" value
-   Try to send some command: salt '*' cmd.run 'ls –l /etc' - which should return results from both minions

Comment: the link http://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/ubuntu14/latest does not exist anymore. you can go to https://repo.saltstack.com/#ubuntu for more instructions

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new answer here since the accepted answer is not workable for automated deployments via `salt-cloud`:

- If you're already on Salt v3004.1 (or later - posting on June 1st, 2022) then `ERROR: Failed to run install_ubuntu_stable_deps()!!!` is most likely being caused by an **out-of-date copy of the bootstrap install script**.
- Update salt-cloud & the bootstrap script with this command: `sudo salt-cloud -u`

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 15 there's a bug report for that here: https://github.com/saltstack/salt-bootstrap/issues/681 which is currently being reviewed. You can try to modify your sources file to use `trusty` and that may resolve the issue as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Give these docs a shot instead: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/ubuntu.html try and install via the repo itself.

Comment: Getting the repo trusted in the base Ubuntu image would also work, yes. ^